# Use Mongoose to search entire DB for all of one key, like Select * All somehow?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to search Mongo using Mongoose for every collection that shares a particular Key. So as an easy example, lets say `Users` and `Animals` are 2 collections and they both have a Key called `Hobbies`, which is type `Array`.

Is there a way to search all of mongo for every instance of the Key `Hobbies`, which would return all of the arrays? Either as a combined array of all values or many separate arrays that I could combine afterwards?

I would imagine in SQL that it would be something like 
`SELECT hobbies FROM * some sort of array situation that I would probably concat`

Basically, an as agnostic of a search as possible.

Comment: There is no built in function. You just iterate over collections and do a find on each collection followed by projection & concatenating hobbies.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks, I will post my solution when I try it out later